# Логическое и физическое расположение виртуального каталога

Tags: windows, веб-сервер, iis

В диспетчере служб IIS для сайта можно добавить виртуальный каталог. Где он будет располагаться логически и физически?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Виртуальный каталог создается на базе существующего. Эта фича нужна для того чтобы размещать каталоги в проекте(сайте) без физического копирования.

При создании виртуального каталога Вы:

- должны выбрать логическое расположение виртуального каталога(относительно
  адреса вашего сайта).
- должны выбрать физический каталог на файловой системе    сервера который
  будет для сайта виртуальным.

Следственно, где виртуальный каталог будет размещен как логически так и физически зависит только от Вас.
более подробно [здесь](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc771804%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)